# NOAA hourly data with python

Tags: python, xml, web-scraping, weather, noaa

Are there any python programs which will grab detailed data from NOAA, particularly the hourly data and the 7-day day/night forecasts?

I found python-weather-api, python-weather, and python-noaa. However they are either no longer supported or lack the data that I'd like.

If not, then I'll probably make one myself although I'd prefer not to reinvent the wheel!

Comment: What exactly do you need, parameters, format (e.g. GRIB)?

Comment: @piokuc Any data structure is fine, so long as there's a way to retrieve it through an api, like most of the scrapers I listed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the [National Digital Forecast Database (NDFD) Simple Object Access Protocol (SOAP) Web Service](http://graphical.weather.gov/xml/) is what you're looking for. You can use SOAP to access NDFD XML objects and parse them with Python quite easily - no 3rd-party libraries needed. If you prefer RESTful services you can [do that too](http://graphical.weather.gov/xml/rest.php).

They even have a great graphic on how SOAP requests work.

[image: use SOAP for fun and profit]